# Power automate get part of web page using xpath or id

Tags: html-parsing, powerapps, power-automate

I am using power automate to read part of secured webpage content using http with Azure AD. I am able to get whole webpage content as text. I am trying to get part of web page text inside a paragraph with id or with a xpath like the below. I tried checking searching connectors for options like read html, read webpage etc but could not find related to add a step. Any suggestion or pointer to read part of webpage using xpath from result of "http with azure ad" connector. The call is not for an API. The call I am trying is for a webpage.

I did the following:
Created a http with azure ad connector with name 'Get web resource'. Successfully signed in with azure ad and able to get content.
used Content = body('Get_web_resource')
used Content as part of email body to trigger email message
Example xpath: //*[@id="Content"]/here/section[3]/ul/li/p
Any option like split if we have challenges xpath option
Content return type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/webcontents/#binary

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use xpath, only in XML.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot/code snippet of the webpage data you are trying to process? Also a screenshot of your current flow setup would be useful. Power Automate has a lot of different expression functions which might be useful in this use case, https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xpath, https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#indexOf or https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#split. 

If you can share a bit more detail I can have a look if I can find something for you.

Comment: The problem with the logic expression `xpath` is that it requires valid XML and will choke on most valid XHTML/HTML. So your probably stuck with the string functions  
Expiscornovus listed above -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#string-functions

Is it possible for you to pass this off to an Azure Function to do the Xpath parsing?